# Date formatting not working right in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, datetime, ios15, ios16

I have weird behavior regarding dates and I cannot figure out if it is due to iOS 16 beta running on a device or due to the different timezone/region.

A user of my app based in London has reported an issue caused by dates showing as such, whether they are am or pm dates which is not the usual case:

```
2022-08-20T7:01:07+0100
```

I format my dates the following way because the backend requires it:

```
   let format = DateFormatter()
   format.timeZone = .current
   format.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"        
   let dateString = format.string(from: self)
```

Therefore, I do not see why the 7 is showing without a 0 before, I should be getting `2022-08-20T07:01:07+0100` instead.

Another case is the following format used for logs:

```
 return "\(Date().to(format: "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")) (\((TimeZone.current.identifier)))"
```

This usually prints `20/04/2022 07:57:15 (Asia/Beirut)` but for that specific user, it prints `20/08/2022 7:02:31 pm (Europe/London)`.

So the problem is that for that user, the dates are not being formatted using a 24 hour rule.

I tried reproducing the user's case by changing my timezone as well as the region of my phone and also playing with the 24-hour Time setting but I cannot reproduce the user's case, neither on iOS 15 or iOS 16.

Does anybody have a clue what could be going wrong or have I missed an important point?

Comment: You should be using the POSIX locale or the special ISO date formatter.

Comment: Great! But do you know a way to reproduce? I can't just release a fix without having tested it first.

Comment: You should be able to reproduce it the way you tried - using a 12h format or a region set to en-GB.

Comment: Excellent! I was able to just now, and your fix works. Thank you!

Comment: I am reluctant to put an answer here because there is certainly a ton of duplicate questions.